# Error of Masking images based on GDAL

Tags: gdal

I want to remove the land area based on mask file; which is a binary image. When I use following **gdal_calc.py** command:

```
gdal_calc.py -A G:\2016.06.MOD\MODIS_JPG\Resize\Arctic.2016059.aqua.1km_Resize.tif -B G:\2016.06.MOD\MODIS_JPG\Mask_Land\Mask.tif --outfile=G:\2016.06.MOD\MODIS_JPG\Mask_Land\test.tif --calc='A*B ' --NoDataValue=0
```

it was produced following **ImportError** message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_calc.py", line 50, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "D:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "D:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "D:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "D:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "D:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Can you give me some advice for the error?

Comment: Probably, your issues are due to a wrong way to assign layer paths.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, your issues are due to a wrong way to assign layer paths. Instead, try out:

```
gdal_calc.py -A G:/2016.06.MOD/MODIS_JPG/Resize/Arctic.2016059.aqua.1km_Resize.tif -B G:/2016.06.MOD/MODIS_JPG/Mask_Land/Mask.tif --outfile=G:/2016.06.MOD/MODIS_JPG/Mask_Land/test.tif --calc='A*B ' --NoDataValue=0
```

I tried out a similar version of your command, but with recommend way to assign paths, with following raster layers (mask2.tif has 50 % of transparency to observe aleatorio.tif):

[image]

My similar **gdal_calc.py** version of your command is:

```
gdal_calc.py -A /home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio.tif -B /home/zeito/pyqgis_data/mask2.tif --outfile=/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/resulting_test_raster.tif --calc='A*B' --NoDataValue=0
```

and when it was run at console it produced a result without any error:

```
0 .. 100 - Done
```

After loading resulting layer at Map Canvas of QGIS, it can be observed that it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: En,sorry.I type gdal_calc.py -A G:/2016.06.MOD/MODIS_JPG/Resize/Arctic.2016059.aqua.1km_Resi‌​ze.tif -B G:/2016.06.MOD/MODIS_JPG/Mask_Land/Mask.tif --outfile=G:/2016.06.MOD/MODIS_JPG/Mask_Land/test.tif --calc='A*B ' --NoDataValue=0 as you said. “C:>” in the question is not in my type contents in OSGeo4W Shell and it's my falut in question.Thanks.